# How to read a 4 column text file into two char arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

C - How to read a 4 column file into two string arrays

I am trying to read in a file of unknown length which has the following format:

```
2082018 1200 79 Meeting
3082018 1300 60 Lunch
4082018 1400 30 Dinner
5082018 0600 90 Work
```

I am trying to get the first column inside an array KEY_arr and the rest of the columns inside VAL_arr such that :

`KEY_Arr[0]` = "2082018" and `VAL_arr[0]` = " 1200 79 Meeting"

I tried two methods, both unsuccessful. In the first method I tried to read in the file using getc in a 2D array:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *inp_cal;
    int word_count = 0;
    char c;
    char arr[50][50];
    int char_count = 0;
    int space_cnt = 0;
    char line[100];
    int line_count = 0;
    inp_cal = fopen("calendar_out.txt", "r");

            if (inp_cal) {
            printf("Processing file...\n");
            while ((c = fgetc(inp_cal)) != EOF) {
                if ((c == ' ' || c == '\n') && space_cnt == 0) {
                    arr[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
                    char_count = 0; //Reset the counter.
                    word_count++;
                    space_cnt = 1;
                } else {
                    if ((c == ' ' || c == '\n') && space_cnt == 1) {
                        word_count++;
                        char_count = 0; 
                    }

                    arr[word_count][char_count] = c;
                    printf("%c", arr[word_count][char_count]);

                    if (char_count < 50) {
                        char_count++;
                    } else {
                        char_count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            printf("no file found.\n");
        }
    printf("\nword count: %d, char count: %d\n\n", word_count, char_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
2082018
1200
 79
 Meeting

3082018
 1300
 60
 Lunch

4082018
 1400
 30
 Dinner

5082018
 0600
 90
 Work
```

I am then stuck when it comes to separating into separate strings for the key and value pairs.

The second method I tried was using `fgets`, but I was unable to get any correct output:

```
if (inp_cal) {
    printf("Processing file...\n");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inp_cal)) {
        char KEY_arr[10];
        char VAL_arr[50];
        char KEY;
        char VAL;

        if (sscanf(line, "%29s%29s", KEY, VAL) != 2) { /* error, bad line */
            printf("Bad line format\n");
        } else {
            KEY_arr[line_count] = KEY;
            VAL_arr[line_count] = VAL;
            printf("%c, %c\n", KEY_arr[line_count], VAL_arr[line_count]);
        }
        line_count++;
    }
} else {
    printf("no file found.\n");
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can improve one of the above methods to read in the 4 column text file and store in two char arrays?

Comment: This question it too broad. You need to understand how strings work in C before attempting to write your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/), since you know the format of the data, and extract every token in a line. Then, the first token is your key, and the other three are meant to be together, so concatenate them with [`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10 // max number of lines to be read
#define VALLEN 100
int main(void)
{
  int key_arr[N], a, count = 0;
  char val_arr[N][VALLEN], b[10], c[10], d[10];
  FILE* fp;
  fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  char bb[33];
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s", &a, b, c, d) != EOF) {
    if(count < N) {
      key_arr[count] = a;
      snprintf(val_arr[count++], VALLEN, "%s %s %s", b, c, d);
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i <count; ++i)
    printf("key=%d, val = %s\n", key_arr[i], val_arr[i]);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
key=2082018, val = 1200 79 Meeting
key=3082018, val = 1300 60 Lunch
key=4082018, val = 1400 30 Dinner
key=5082018, val = 0600 90 Work
```

Comment: This is simple and effective, thanks! The only issue I see is that `sprintf()` may  cause a buffer overflow since the number of lines and `val_arr` string size are unknown. Also, the leading zero from the first parameter in `val_arr` is being missed such that `0600` becomes `600`

Comment: @DawnofTime you are welcome! It cannot use a width specifier it seems, so yes. About the number of lines, there is this if condition inside the body of the loop that takes caution. However, that's the trade off between simple code and some memory getting wasted, a fair trade off if you ask me. If your memory is really precious (which I don't think you are programming in such an environment), then you could first count the lines of the file, and the length of every line (remember the what was the max length seen), and then dynamically allocate memory. However, this is costly in terms of perform

Comment: -ance, since it has to parse the file twice. As for the `0600` @DawnofTime you were right. I modified the code to treat the last three tokens as strings, where 10 was a size I picked according to your data, but you might want to adjust that accordingly. Moreover, I now used `snprintf()`, which can prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information. Even though what I originally asked for is answered, I keep on getting an `fscanf()` return of -1. This is usually the case when there is some sort of error when reading from the file.        int `ret = fscanf(inp_cal, "%d %s %s %s", &a, b, c, d);` prints out -1. This most probably is an issue from my end however, and so question marked as answered.

Comment: Hmm, try experimenting with different format specifiers @DawnofTime, since this approach is sensitive to the data's format. Debug it, and if you still have issues. then, maybe tomorrow, post a new question, and if you want, share it with me. Good luck!